# Resolving action URL from action method in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got controller code like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Foo()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

and I would like to find URL of these methods, using reflection or some `nameof`-like method. 
It would be great if it could be called from everywhere in application, or at least in middlewares to be able to filter requests by actions.

The results I'd like to see would be:

- For `GetUrl(ValuesController.Get)` I'd get `api/Values`
- For `GetUrl(ValuesController.Foo)` I'd get `api/Values/Foo`

I do not need these URLs in exactly this form, they might have preceding `/` or not etc. but I am wondering if this is somehow possible, no matter if in runtime or in compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

UrlHelper's Action function is what you are looking for:

```
UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
string url = u.Action(varControllerNameUsingReflection, varActionNameUsingReflection, null);
```

Comment: But I have to manually remove `Controller` part from this controller name. Or don't I?

Comment: Yes but only if it ends with "Conttoller"

Comment: This syntax doesn't work in .NET Core MVC, it seems to be method from full .NET Framework. Moreover, this needs to be run inside MVC middleware, thus making your solution unrelated to my question.

Comment: @DominikSzymański then why did you add mvc related tags to your question? My solution is related with your question, referring the related tags. By the way, UrlHelper is included in asp.net core too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Because .NET Core MVC is still .NET MVC, just newer version. And yes, it is included in .NET Core, but works a bit different and cannot be injected outside MVC middleware. I am using MVC, but I want to be able to retrieve URLs in other places too, like other middlewares, services etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the action in the same controller and you also want to get complete URL:

```
var notificationUrl = this.Url.Action(
                nameof(ControllerActionMethod),
                this.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName,
                null,
                this.HttpContext.Request.Protocol,
                this.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString())
```